# Почему в БД передается строка с кавычками?

Tags: python, mysql

```
a = "aaa"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_title) VALUES ("%s\")', (a))
```

В БД записывается как `"aaa"`, а нужно `ааа`.

Как импортировать без кавычек?

Comment: Стереть кавычки вокруг `%s` очевидно

Comment: Фига, работаете с БД вордпресса через питон.

Comment: Нужно передать в следующем виде 'aaa'

Comment: попробуйте так `cur.execute('INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title) VALUES (?)', (a))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, не надо обрамлять `%s` кавычками, во-вторых методу `cur.execute()` надо передавать кортеж или список в качестве второго параметра:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_title) VALUES (%s)', (a, ))
```

PS `(a)` - кортежем не является:

```
In [66]: a = "aaa"

In [67]: type( (a) )
Out[67]: str

In [68]: type( (a,) )
Out[68]: tuple
```